# Bootstrap input group addon splitting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input

When trying to make my website mobile-responsive, i met with a problem that an input group addon is splitting from the text box. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934844/why-is-bootstrap-input-group-input-group-addon-splitting) question. But I haven't used any col-md-....s or col-xs-....s here.

My code is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="bottom_section_vide" class="well">
  <div id="date_container_panel" align="center">
    <div id="date_container" class="panel-body">
      <form id="date_form" role="form" class="form-inline row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="checkin_field" type="text" placeholder="Check In" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
            <i class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar btn-link" id="chin_cla"></i></i>
          </div>
        </div>&emsp;&emsp;
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="checkout_field" type="text" placeholder="Check Out" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" disabled />
            <i class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar btn-link" id="chout_cla"></i></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My output is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT506.png)

Comment: Your example appears to work as one would expect. You should add any CSS your applying as well.

Comment: @vanburen My CSS: 
    @media(max-width:767px){
        #checkin_field, #checkout_field{
            height: 15px;
            width: 140px;
            appearance: none;
            box-shadow:none;
            border-radius: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

Comment: @vanburen this is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=a5vUN0zELL

Comment: Remove `height: 15px; width: 140px;` you're setting inside the media query.

Comment: @vanburen it's working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

give a particular width to the container of the elements.

```
   #date_container{
    width : <value>px;
   }
```